# Is this the best method to create this table? (fiddle)

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table [that would look like this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mq8nE/1/)

I'm wondering if the current code is the best way to create this appearance?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="margin">
   <table width="720" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="95" valign="top" class="style1"></th>
          <th width="321" valign="top" class="style1">Column A</th>
          <th width="369" valign="top" class="style1">Column B</th>
          <th width="331" valign="top" class="style1">Column C</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="95" valign="top"><p>Row A</p></td>
          <td width="321" valign="top"><p>Content</p></td>
          <td width="369" valign="top"><p>Content</p></td>
          <td width="331" valign="top"><p>Content</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="95" valign="top"><p>Row B</p></td>
          <td width="321" valign="top"><p>Content</p></td>
          <td width="369" valign="top"><p>Content</p></td>
          <td width="331" valign="top"><p>Content</p></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p, em, font, table, tr, th, td, thead, tbody, tfoot
{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

table   { 
table-layout: auto; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; empty-cells: show;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Alef', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 940px;
    background-color: #FFC;
    min-height: 632px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.style1 {
    background-color: #03C;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#margin {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-top: 40px;

}

td,th {
    color: #678197;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #903;
    border-left: 1px solid #903;
    padding: .3em 1em 2em 1em;
    text-align:left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#CCC;
}

table {
    border-top: 1px solid #903;
    border-right: 1px solid #903;
    background-color: #F4F2F3;
}
```

**Questions for example:**

1. Is this a proper use of `thead`,`th` and `tbody` tags?
2. Do I really have to apply `class="style1"` to each td? (If I apply it only to the `TR`, it would not effect the font correctly.
3. Is this the right way to leave a blank cell at the top left corner?
4. Should I define the `border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` in CSS instead?
5. I want the Table's Width to be Fixed, should I indicate it in HTML (like now) or CSS?
6. **What do You recommend to do with the Cell's Width?** should I indicate them on every cell? they don't make a difference here anyway (you can see that the total width is bigger than the whole table's width) so I'm not sure what to do here. I'm going to have changing amounts of text in each cell.
7. Is this the right way to create the red border between the cells and the table? (define only right and top for the `table`, and only left and bottom for `td`)

Thanks!

Comment: if you really want the right way to build tables, well it's just to not use tables, easy :)

Comment: @sbaaaang, there's absolutely nothing wrong with tables when used for the correct reason.

Comment: @Prisoner sure but he asked the best practice , and this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design ;)

Comment: This is going to be tabular data (and not layout), so I think it's the right way to go here.

Comment: @sbaaaang `...philosophy eschewing the use of HTML tables for page **layout** control purposes.` and `More recent times have seen an increasing understanding among web content professionals of the advantages of restricting the use of HTML tables to their intended and semantic purpose — i.e. laying out tabular data or other information.`

Comment: as @Prisoner said, tables are great for showing tabular data, which, in this example, it is exactly the case.

Comment: @rockyraw as you wish guys if you preferr tables to easy divs np :)

Comment: @sbaaaang, read your own source, don't be so close minded.

Comment: try to style a table then to style divs, i don't think you'll use same css lines of code ;)

Comment: @Prisoner i'm not closed mind my nickname should lol confirm that, i'm just for better performance and mantainance

Comment: and you can find all the main things i'm talking about just scrolling this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design

Comment: but @sbaaaang don't you find it funny to avoid tables at all costs when all you really need is to represent data in a tabular format? (i.e. the semantic purpose of a table?)

Comment: @blurfus if you don't like to care about such things http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design ;)

Comment: probably tables are only good for printing the html page imho

Comment: i mean it's like to use an Arial font-family or a custom font-family, as you wish , BEST PRACTICE = Arial, PREFERRED PRACTICE = custom font, don't you think ? @blurfus

Comment: @sbaaaang you keep pointing to that page; it talks about *page* layout, not table layout.  Perhaps you cannot tell the difference since you seem to think that tableless layout is a silver bullet for everything

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a Code Review (btw, we have a SE site for that)

Comment: @blurfus i'm not here to link you all the web talking about tableless benefits, if you ask me can i use tables i say yes, if you ask me which the best practice i say not use them ;)

Comment: @sbaaaang It sounds to me that you are confusing best practices for page layout with best way to show tabular data.  I agree with you with best practices for page layout is to avoid using tables (no one is disputing that).  But it is crazy to grab tabular data and take it out of a table and convert them to divs just to comply with tableless dogma.  Use the right tool for the right case is what we are trying to say.  Even most modern CSS and layout frameworks have CSS annotations to accommodate tables and to decorate them correctly.

Comment: @blurfus i agree with you at 50% the other 50% is the performance etc stuff , divs are better anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts/answers

1. They seem correct usage for the tags
2. You don't really have to create specific classes for each td or tr as long as you identify your table.  for example, you could have:

   ```
   <table id="myUniquelyIdentiedTable">
      <tr>
         <th>Column A</th>
         <th>Column B</th>
      <tr>
   ....
   </table>
   ```

and then in your CSS, you could do something like:

```
#myUniquelyIdentifiedTable th{
...
}

#myUniquelyIdentifiedTable td{
 ...
}
```

etc.

3) I tend to actually specify a blank `&nbsp;` for some cross-browser compatability but semantically, there is nothing wrong with it.

4) you could do that; I don't remember them being too hard to do it but it is not a straight (1 to 1) conversion.

5) restricting width you can wrap the table with a container and restrict the container to a width.  I.e.

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
  <!-- your table here -->
</div>

// in your CSS
.tableWrapper{
   width: 400px;
}

.tableWrapper table{
   width: 100%;
}
```

6) For a cell's width, I typically just set it on the THs but not all the TDs.  If possible, you can give related THs a name (i.e. `<th class="single-width">`) and then style the width with CSS `.single-width{ width: 100px; }`

7) I would not use that approach.  I would set the background colour of the table to be red and then the background of THs and TDs to be different.  The cellspacing and border setting would give you the necessary border colour. (this is old-school, but works - there are other ways to style tables as well)